# Kirchoff's Second Law

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I am failing to get a proper intuition on Kirchoff's law. If any closed loop has sum of pd and emf equal to 0, does that mean that this picture's loop also follows the same? I am not able to draw a valid conclusion. How does $(1\ \rm{\Omega})I_1+(2\ \rm{\Omega})I_2=0$?
[image]

Comment: Thats a really simple circuit, what makes you think it would not follow Kirchoff's law? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @HugoV can you help me now?

Comment: Before we can help you need to give more information like @HugoV has said

Comment: Sense(clockwise/anticlockwise) of application of law matter. Apply a negative sign while moving opposite to direction of current

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly not true that $1*I_1+2*I_2=0$. So lets call  $V_p$, $V_q$ the potentials at point P and Q. Then, assuming the ammeter to be ideal, you can see that the potential difference between both resistors is $\Delta V=V_q - V_p$. Then of course, because of conservation of energy, using $\Delta V=R*I$, you have:
$$R_1*I_1=\Delta V=R_2*I_2$$
From this equation it is clear that: $$1*I_1-2*I_2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Kirchhoff has two laws: the current law $\sum I=0$ and the voltage loop law $\sum V=0$.

- The current law is applied at one particular point - in that point you sum up all incoming and outgoing currents. It must equal zero, meaning that all incoming charge every second must also leave every second. Otherwise you would have charge accumulating there (which clearly doesn't happen).
- The voltage law is applied around a loop, like the one in your picture, and simply states that if there is steady state, meaning that the circuit is balanced and the current constant, then the total voltage will necessarily be "spent" or "dropped" throughout the loop. A voltage source (such as a battery) will *add* to the voltage (positive), while other component will "*spend*" and *decrease* the voltage (negative). If they didn't "spend" it all (as is the case in a short-circuit, where there are no resistances to "absorb" the voltage) then the current would continue speeding up and up and up - and it wouldn't be a steady state.

When you say $I_{1.1}+I_{2.2}=0$, then it looks like you are trying to use the current law. In that case, you must also say exactly which point you are looking at (and define which currents $I_{1.1}$ and $I_{2.2}$ represent) before this makes any sense. And remember that these two currents must be considered with sign (a current leaving the chosen point is negative), so one of these must be negative.